# Use kvkbd without window manager

Tags: linux, kde, virtual-keyboard

I am currently developing a kiosk application in QML and I want to use kvkbd virtual keyboard for user input.

When used with a window manager (such as icewm), kvkbd works well, but since my application runs without a window manager (it is a kiosk application), kvkbd does not send the keys to the focused field (e.g. a text input).

A simple script for testing would be (I am using OpenSUSE 13.1):

```
X :1
export DISPLAY=:1
kvkbd
xterm
```

After switching to the new display (Ctrl + Alt + F_digit), I am able to send input to xterm from keyboard, but not from kvkbd.

Do you have any ideas how can explicitly specify the focused window to kvkbd?
Or any ideas how I can accomplish this issue?

Thanks.